# Ti-84 +CE If-Then-else Syntax error

Tags: if-statement, calculator, texas-instruments

**EDIT: Full code has been included, because it seems possible that the error may lie in the Else or End commands that are also part of the If-Then conditional.**

Programming newbie here. I did see the many other if-else syntax error questions but seeing them, was worried that they did not address exactly whatever problem is going on in my case.

I have the following lines of commands on a TI-84 program I'm making.

- This is part of a program I made that solves for the other sides/angles of a triangle given some other sides/angles.
- Below are the lines of programming I included for the ambiguous case (SSA triangle), which happens if the supplement of the angle B solved for (given Side A, Angle A, and Side B) is less than 180 when added to the given Angle A. In this case, there are two different triangle cases-- one with angle B as the initially solved angle B, and the other with angle B being equal to the supplement of the 1st case's angle B.
- Otherwise, if this condition is not satisfied (the supplement + Angle A is greater or equal to 180), then only one triangle exists.
- Lbl 0 is just a label these lines of programming go to after all triangle values are calculated. It then calculates certain other values of this triangle based off of all of the angles & sides.

  ```
  Lbl 2
  Disp "Side A, Side B, Angle A"
  Pause 
  Prompt A,B,D
  sin(B*sin(D)/A)→E
  If ((180-E+D)<180)
  Then 
  Disp "Case 1"
  Pause 
  180-D-E→F
  A*sin(F)/sin(D)→C
  Disp "Angle B=",E
  Disp "Angle C=",F
  Disp "Side C=",C
  (A+B+C)/2→S
  √(S(S-A)(S-B)(S-C))→H
  Disp "Area=",H
  Pause 
  Disp "Case 2"
  Pause 
  180-E→E
  180-D-E→F
  A*sin(F)/sin(D)→C
  (A+B+C)/2→S
  √(S(S-A)(S-B)(S-C))→H
  Disp "Angle B=",E
  Disp "Angle C=",F
  Disp "Side C=",C
  Pause 
  Disp "Area=",H
  Goto 0 
  Else 
  180-D-E→F
  A*sin(F)/sin(D)→C
  Disp "Angle B=",E
  Disp "Angle C=",F
  Disp "Side C=",C
  Pause 
  Goto 0
  End
  ```

The square is just an inverse (^-1) sign. It formats correctly in the TI Connect CE software that I'm using.

I assumed that the If-then lines were the problem lines, because removing them removes the SYNTAX error. Another possibility is that I set up my Else And End incorrectly, though I did consult the TI-Basic Developer Wiki and my setup seemed to be right.

What is wrong with the syntax of the If-then lines that is causing this error?

Comment: Most likely you must encapsulate the condition in parenthesis, can you try `:If ((180-E+D)<180)` ? Also, have you ended the `Then` clause with an `End` ? See [The If Command - TI-Basic Developer](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/if) for more information.

Comment: Funny you mention that-- TI-Basic Developer was was actually the first place I checked. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything that explained where I was going wrong. I will amend my question to include the full lines of programming, which might be messy due to inexperience.

Comment: Also--I tried encapsulating the condition as suggested, but the syntax error still showed up.

Answer (score 1):

I did not see any problems when I tried this on my calculator. The only thing that I thought could have been an error was the parenthesis around the if argument...

```
If ((180-E+D)<180)
```

vs

```
If 180-E+D<180
```

The program worked for me, so I can't identify a problem...

If you get the error and choose Goto, what line of the code does the calculator say the error is on?